# App Android após várias requsições recebe SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, tomcat

Eu desenvolvi um aplicativo de cardápio para *Android*, o garçom pelo app vê todas as mesas, pelo aplicativo abre a mesa, faz o pedido que sai na cozinha e por ai vai.

O web service retorna um **JSON** para cada requisição e faz as transações no banco de dados, o mesmo fica rodando em um **tomcat**.

O aplicativo depois de um certo tempo de uso não consegue mais se conectar ao servidor, após testes vi que recebo um `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`.

```
private static String sCookie;

public static String acessar(String url){
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    String conteudo = "";

        try {               
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(url).openConnection()));                       
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Close");
            if(sCookie != null && !"".equals(sCookie))
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sCookie);   

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == 200) {
                conteudo = streamToStr(conn.getInputStream());
                 String cookie = conn.getHeaderField("set-cookie");
                    if(cookie != null && cookie.length() > 0)
                        sCookie = cookie;                   
            }

            return conteudo;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){    
            ex.printStackTrace();               
        } finally {
            if(conn != null)
                conn.disconnect();              
        }   
        return conteudo;
}
```

Pensei que fosse o **tomcat**, alterei as configurações padrões do `Connector`, mas não resolveu.

```
<Connector  port="9090"
                enableLookups="false" 
                protocol = "HTTP/1.1"
                acceptorThreadCount="2"
                maxThreads="300" 
                connectionTimeout="30000"
                compressableMimeTypes="text/*,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
                compressionMinSise="2048"
                noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                maxSpareThreads="150" 
                maxRequestsPerChild="20000"
                compression="force"          
                redirectPort="8443"
                keepAlive="true"
                keepAliveTimeOut="20000">
    </Connector>
```

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda para tentar descobrir o que pode estar ocasionando este problema.

Comment: Porque tão pouco tempo de timeout? 5000 está em milesgundos ou seja o timeout é de 5 segundos, o padrão para requisições HTTP é de 30000 (30 segundos)

Comment: Antes o tempo de timeout era de 15 segundos, quando o garçom ia consultar a lista de mesas, o app abre o progressDialog pedindo para ele aguardar, e ele ficava ali por 15 segundos até dar o timeoutexception, então resolvi diminuir por que independente do tempo, tem um certo momento que o app não consegue mais se comunicar com o servidor.

Comment: Ok @Edson, mas o padrão para TimeOut é de 30 segundos. Só para esclarecer. Você considerou em chamar o seu webservice usando o REST Client para verificar se demora?

Comment: Como isso ocorre depois de varias requisições, seria bom verificar se seus scripts estão **abrindo** e **fechando** a conexão com o **banco de dados**. Verifique se os processos iniciados pelo tomcat se finalizam ao fim da requisição.

Comment: Oi @HiagoSouza, sim eu cheguei a testar usando Rest e obtive os mesmos erros.

Comment: Outro detalhe que esqueci de mencionar, quando desenvolvi o app, eu fiz o testes no meu moto x não houve em nenhum momento esse tipo de erro, os garçons utilizam um samsung galaxy ace duos e com eles acontece o que sitei na postagem.

Comment: Ok, vi sua classe do android agora. Esta faltando um conn.disconnect();

Comment: esta no finally o disconnect();

Answer (score 0):

> Sua conexão esta ficando aberta, esse pode ser o motivo de funcionar e depois começar a dar problema.

**Possíveis causas:**

- Verifique se o **conn.disconnect()** esta sendo acionado.
- Verifique se o seu webservice esta fechando todas as conexões com o
  banco de dados e se o processo deles é finalizado porque após  esta
  sendo acionado porque o máximo de conexões que esta autorizada no
  tomcat é 300 `maxThreads="300"` .

---

```
private static String sCookie;

public static String acessar(String url){
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    String conteudo = "";

        try {               
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(url).openConnection()));                       
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Close");
            if(sCookie != null && !"".equals(sCookie))
                conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", sCookie);   

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == 200) {
                conteudo = streamToStr(conn.getInputStream());
                 String cookie = conn.getHeaderField("set-cookie");
                    if(cookie != null && cookie.length() > 0)
                        sCookie = cookie;                   
            }

            conn.disconnect();

            return conteudo;
        }
        catch(Exception ex){    
            ex.printStackTrace();               
        } finally {
            if(conn != null)
                conn.disconnect();              
        }   
        return conteudo;
}
```

Comment: esta no finally o disconnect();

Comment: perdão não tinha visto.

Comment: Mas você depurou? Viu se realmente ele desconecta?

Comment: sim, depurei, ele realmente desconecta.

Comment: E no seu webservice? Ele esta abrindo e fechando as conexões no banco de dados como perguntei nos comentários da pergunta?

Comment: poderia postar o seu método no WS para eu verificar?

Comment: Sim, as conexões com o banco de dados são abertas e fechadas logo após o select no banco.

Comment: E os processos do tomcat também estão normal?

Comment: Para que você mesmo possa ver, eu tirei 2 prints do probe (ferramenta para o gerenciamento remoto e o monitoramento em tempo real do Tomcat). 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1DPcYy_RrsYVjJCSW9vbGttbzQ/view?pli=1

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1DPcYy_RrsYamdFLUZhVVNoekk/view?pli=1

a aplicação responde na porta 9090, e o ip 192.168.200.28 é o da minha máquina, o 172.16.200.12 é o do smartphone.

Comment: ok pelo que eu vi o processo do smartphone está encerrado e o seu tempo foi de 00:02:18.347 é normal o processo ter ficado 2 minutos ? Porque foi oque aconteceu, ficou 2 minutos só que no smartphone quando deu os 5 segundos ele deu timeout porque não obteve a resposta.

Comment: Você sabe o porque o processo ficou tanto tempo assim? Já depurou o serviço que é chamado para ver o porque da demora ? porque se o tempo for esse mesmo, você tem que subir o timeout para mais tempo no android e não diminuir ele.

Comment: Aquele é o tempo desde o momento que o processo foi finalizado até a hora atual, tanto é que fiz uma requisição do smartphone e fui no probe olhar, o status aparece como Ended e o proc.time 0:00:07.701.

Comment: Edson você chamou o WebService na mão usando o REST ? Chame ele e olhe o tempo médio de resposta ai ajusta no seu timeout o padrão é 30 como eu já havia dito antes, mas pode ser que o serviço especifico esteja necessitando de um tempo a mais para te responder.